# How to render and dispaly variables and values from Django in HTML

Tags: python, django, django-templates, summernote, django-template-filters

I am experimenting with Django and templating system. At the moment I'd like to find the best way to render values from variables/objects in HTML. For example, I have a template tag like this:

```
{{ single.title }}
```

Now, rendering this is perfectly fine when I add it to templates. But I want to know how can I render this in WYSIWYG editor like django-summernote - even if I go and add this in HTML code. it still writes this as a string with curly braces but doesn't render the variable value.

Basically, I want to be able to use these variables/values and render them in the WYSIWYG field (say a blog post content). I tried with {% autoescape off %} and number of other things but still ends up rendering this as a regular text.

[image: Rendered as a regular text, does not recognize django template specifics]

Comment: What is the output of `{{ single.summary_points|linebreaks }}`?  `{{ single.summary_points|safe }}`?

Comment: It's the list... but you can ignore that - let's assume that I want to display the title of my blog post {{ single.title }} - as I said, I'm trying to figure out the ability where I can just add these tags to the post content (summernote, TinyMCE, any WYSIWYG, really).

Comment: Can you post your template?

Comment: @riNg sure thing, here's the relevant part - the entire template is somewhat large and complex. 
`<div class="col-10 main-article-body-text"> <p class="border-bottom-dotted pb-3 pt-4"><em><strong>{{ single.excerpt }}</strong></em><br></p>  {% autoescape off %} {{ single.content }} {% endautoescape %} </div>`